# PHP will not echo variables

Tags: php, output, echo

I have the following very basic PHP script:

```
    <?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

echo "This is the username: ";
echo $username;
?>
```

And this is the output:

```
This is the username:
```

I have my username and password parameters in my url. Why won't it echo the username?

Comment: Maybe they are passed by GET? As you ssy they re in the url. Use: $_GET instead of $_POST

Comment: Data passed via the URL is found in the `$_GET` array not `$_POST`.

Comment: You can also use `$_REQUEST` to access both URL and POST parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't display because the parameters in the URL are parsed as GET and not POST.

Use `$_GET['username']` to get the data from `http://www.somesite.com?username=yash`

References:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm
- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Answer (score -1):

Try echoing the entire $_POST array.  This might lead you to the problem.

```
echo  "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>";
```